# Animating using D3 transitions vs using CSS animation

Tags: css, d3.js

I am trying to determine if there is a difference between using D3.transition to apply animation on elements or use CSS animations/keyframes. Is there a preferred way? Is one more performant than other?

Example:
I want a `<circle>` to infinitely animate between opacity of 0.5 and 1 giving it a pulsating animation.

I can either do:

```
function pulsatingAnimation() {
    circleSelection.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('opacity', 0.5)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('opacity', 1)
        .on('end', pulsatingAnimation);
}
```

OR in my CSS file

```
.circle { animation: pulse 1s ease infinite alternate; }
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  100% {
   opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Generally CSS opacity animation is a good bet for performance. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Comment: Performance apart, there are tons of complex and intricate D3 transitions that you simply cannot reproduce using CSS.